# Bash: make: command not found even after installing msys-make pakage

Tags: bash, git

The error in the title is what appears on my Bash on Windows 10 when I try using `make` I did read many tips and none seems to work when I tried `mingw-get install msys-make`.

I got the error message that it's already installed on my pc. Now I dunno what to do, even when the package is installed, `bash: make: command not found` is still there. On the other hand, I did add almost all the possible path to PATH, and sometimes the error change to

```
/mingw64/make-4.3/tests/scripts/variables/make: line 3: =: command not found
/mingw64/make-4.3/tests/scripts/variables/make: line 5: =: command not found
/mingw64/make-4.3/tests/scripts/variables/make: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `q!'
/mingw64/make-4.3/tests/scripts/variables/make: line 7: `run_make_test(q!'
```

Comment: Try finding out where `make` is located and add its path to the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: i did that already :(

Comment: Please update your question with the steps you took.

Comment: open a new terminal window and type `echo PATH="$PATH"` . Edit your Q to show include tht output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should add its path to the $PATH variable and reboot Windows. OS updates viriables after reboot.